# Is there any similar module like context other than panels in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

Please help me in this , I need to configure my blocks in different pages in different regions. So i need a contributed module in drupal other than context and panels.
Regards
Krijesh PV

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you or don't you want to use context?

The only alternative I know is to do it in a custom module implementing the "hook_page_alter" hook.